# Suggestions on how to verify this partial differential equation solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

would appreciate some guidance on the following:

Consider the function $z(x,y)=(x+y)\ln(x/y)$.

> Show by substitution that $x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=z$.

I have rewritten the equation using basic log rules to try and separate $x$ and $y$, hoping this will shed light on the next step but its still not clear, i.e.

$$z=x\ln(x/y)+y\ln(x/y)$$

$$z=x\ln(x)-x\ln(y)+y\ln(x)-y\ln(y)$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $z=x\ln(x)-x\ln(y)+y\ln(x)-y\ln(y)$, then $\partial z/\partial x=\ln(x/y)+1+y/x$, and $\partial z/\partial y=-x/y+\ln(x/y)-1$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just differentiate ansd substitute in one side to get the other
$$x[\color{red}{\ln x+1}-\ln y+\color{blue}{\frac{y}{x}}]+y[-\frac{x}{y}+\ln x- \ln y-1]
\\=x\ln(x)-x\ln(y)+y\ln(x)-y\ln(y)=z$$

Comment: Thank you both very much. From your responses I have worked out that for ∂z/∂x I should use the product rule on xln(x) and -xln(y) to get ln(x/y)+1+y/x. For the xln(x) I get 1*ln(x)+x*1/x = ln(x)+1. But, for -xln(y) I get -1*ln(y)-x*1/y=-ln(y)-x/y. Therefore for ∂z/∂x I get ln(x/y)+1-x/y yet I see in your answers you both have ln(x/y)+1+y/x in ∂z/∂x? What am I missing! Thank you again very much in advance?

Comment: I couldn't read your comment, red=derivative of first term, black=2nd, blue=3rd, o=4th. One more thing is that differentiating partially w.r.t $x$, you consider y as constant

Comment: @AndyKellener do you accept this or you need it more clear

Comment: hi my confusion is over y/x in blue, which I have worked out was derived using the product rule on the −xln(y) part of the equation. I instead get: 1*ln(y)-x*1/y=-ln(y)-x/y, yet your answer has -ln(y)+y/x? ie you have +x/y while i get -x/y. I can tell a am making a basic error. Thanks.

Comment: it is one function since $y$ is considered as a constant

Comment: I have got it. Thank you: ∂z/∂x on the −xln(y) part of the equation is just -ln(y), then for the yln(x) part I get y*1/x. Then when I bring all the terms in ∂z/∂x together I get ln(x)+1-ln(y)+y*1/x which = ln(x/y)+1+y/x. thanks again to both of you....

Comment: I accept...graciously.